# difference between compressed_image and compressed_depth_image

Tags: ros, compressed-image-transport, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I am wondering what's difference between compressed_image and compressed_depth_image?

If I want to compress raw image as much as possible for high resolution wireless video streaming, which one should I choose?

Thanks for any help in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58642/difference-between-compressed_image-and-compressed_depth_image/) by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 441 on 2013-03-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These message types are for sending fairly different types of messages between nodes:

- **[compressed_image](http://www.ros.org/wiki/compressed_image_transport)** - standard color images

  - 3-channel (RGB), 8-bit
  - compressed using either JPG or PNG formats, with user-specified settings
- **[compressed_depth_image](http://www.ros.org/wiki/compressed_depth_image_transport)** - depth image (e.g. from kinect or stereo cameras)

  - 1-channel, either 32-bit float or 16-bit integer
  - compressed using PNG format

Your application sounds like it involves standard (not "3D") video data, so I would choose the compressed_image format.  See [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_transport/Tutorials/ExaminingImagePublisherSubscriber#Changing_Transport-Specific_Behavior) tutorial for examples of how to adjust the compression "quality" to achieve your desired performance.

As far as I know, though, the [image_transport](http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_transport) package hides the details of the specific transports from your application.  You shouldn't have to interface with a compressed_image directly.  The image_transport exposes images on both sides as standard [Image](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html) messages.  See the examples at [these](http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_transport/Tutorials) tutorials.  You can toggle between different methods by setting the `~image_transport` parameter to see the effect on performance.  In particular, you may want to look into the [theora](http://www.ros.org/wiki/theora_image_transport) streaming-video method.

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-03-21**:
The usually used compressing algorithms don't work with a depth image (32-bit float or 16-bit integer). This is the reason for this spacial plugin.